# Vue Axios retrieve Response ID of object within list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have an Vue.js application and im using AXIOS to return API calls from the database. I have managed to return the whole list of the database entries (`findAll`) however I want to execute `findOne` functionality based on the ID which was returned by `findAll` whose response will contain all details with their unique IDs, `findOne` will take these unique IDs and attach them to url parameter.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Returns list using **Vue.js**

```vue
<div class="results" v-if="showResult">
  <div v-for="(response) in response">
    <div class="card-divider">
      <p>{{response.name}} {{response.id}}
        <!--Potentially a link such as url/{response.id}-->
        <button @click="getCurrencyOne();">X</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**AXIOS** find all

```js
findAll() {
  axios
    .get(`/url/`)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            this.response = response.data

            if (response.data.length == 1){
                console.log("There is one entry")
            }
            else if (response.data.length ) {
                console.log("There are " + response.data.length + " entries")
            }

            this.showResult = true
        }
    });
}
```

**AXIOS** find one

```js
findOne() {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',

    //1 would be the id of the object
    url: 'url' + 1,

    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.response = response.data.id
      // this.test = response.data.map(currency => currency.id)
      console.log(response.data.id)

      console.log(this.response)
  })
}
```

Comment: what are you using in backend?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Spring-Boot

Comment: you should handle that inside your rest service

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I do have a function which retrieves the findOne function within the backend for example /url/1, which finds by ID, however I dont know how to assign the ID to the URL parameter from front end

Comment: is that `id` a data or a computed property ? if so you should do something like `axios.get('url'+this.id)`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim ID is data

Comment: please provide your data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass that `id` to your method `getCurrencyOne(resp.id)`:

```
getCurrencyOne(id) {
  axios({
      method: 'GET',

      //1 would be the id of the object
      url: 'url/' + id,

      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.response = response.data.id
      // this.test = response.data.map(currency => currency.id)
      console.log(response.data.id)

      console.log(this.response)
    })
}
```

```
<div class="results" v-if="showResult">
  <div v-for="(resp) in response">
    <div class="card-divider">
      <p>{{resp.name}} {{resp.id}}

        <button @click="getCurrencyOne(resp.id)">X</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so only thing in theory I was missing was actually defining the ID, thanks for help

Comment: you're welcome, could accept my answer if it helped you?